# VBA Excel Macro - Delete Text After 2 First Words

Tags: vba, excel

I need a simple Macro or Excel formula that I can record to delete in specific Column (F) all text afetr the first two words (sometimes there is just 1 word and sometimes 3-4).

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use LEFT with FIND and SUBSTITUTE:

```
=LEFT(F1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(F1," ","}}}",2)&"}}}"))
```

[image]

---

For vba use this UDF:

```
Function firstTwo(str As String) As String
Dim strArr() As String
strArr = Split(str)
If UBound(strArr) = LBound(strArr) Then
    firstTwo = strArr(0)
Else
    firstTwo = strArr(0) & " " & strArr(1)
End If

End Function
```

You would call it from the sheet:

```
=firstTwo(F1)
```

And copy down.